# .Net 6 SignalR - data transfer rate

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, asp.net-core-webapi, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I try so send 1 gigabyte of data from an ASP.NET Core Web API server (.NET 6 runtime) with SignalR to a client.

**The application flow is as follows:** Client calls controller endpoint to start a long running process. This controller endpoint immediately returns Http 202 and starts a background process. Then the client starts a SignalR connection and waits for callbacks. The server send the data with `IHubContext` as soon as the calculation is finished. The resulting object is around 1 gigabyte in size.

**The problem:** with Windows resource monitor, I can see that the SignalR client receives a maximum of 70 kilobytes per second. Transferring the data would take hours.

**To verify the problem:** if I return the 1 gigabyte data directly via the controller endpoint (synchronous HTTP call without callback), then I get data transfer rates of 300 kilobytes per second. This is still slow, but is due to the company network. But it shows that theoretically a higher data transfer rate would be possible than with SignalR.

I adjusted the buffer size in both the client and the server. However, this does not seem to have any effect on the data transfer rate.

Does anyone have any idea what limits the SignalR data transfer rate and how I can fix it?

**Server**

```
  routes.MapHub<ValuationHub>("/ValuationHub", options =>
  {
      options.ApplicationMaxBufferSize = 100000000; //100mb
      options.TransportMaxBufferSize = 100000000; //100mb
  });
```

**Client**

```
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .WithUrl(acceptedResult.SignalRCallbackUrl, opts =>
    {
        opts.TransportMaxBufferSize = 100000000;
        opts.ApplicationMaxBufferSize = 100000000;
        opts.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    })
    .Build();
```

Comment: As you already adjusted the buffer sizes. In addition, the other factors that you should consider is, compression, you better compress the data before sending it over SignalR and after receiving also need decompression. Network and your server capacity also influence data transmission. Most importnatly, if your client loads are high, you should think of parallel processor brackground service and also if possible can consider scall your SignalR hub. SignalR supports scaling out using backplanes like Azure SignalR Service or Redis